# Asynchronous email validation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to write a method for validating if the email already exists in the Firebase Authentication database. So if a user types an email, it should check in the database if it already exists. If so I want to display a message in HTML using FormControl.

Here is my code for the method I wrote:

```
checkEmail(control:FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any>{
    const answer = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(control.value === "someone@hotmail.com"){
          resolve({'emailTaken': true})
        }else{
          resolve(null);
        }
      },1500);
    });
    return answer;
  }
```

As you can see it is checking a static value ("someone@hotmail.com"). I want to be able to check on all the users in my database if that email already exists. I was thinking maybe I could fix this by getting a list of all the users that are in the db, putting them in a list and then looping through the list to see if an email is equal to the user input. But I haven't found a single Firebase function for this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

*EDIT: This is my service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  token:string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

    if(localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

   }

  signup(email:string, passwd:string){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwd).catch(
      error=> console.log(error)
    );
  }

  isLoggedIn(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  login(email:string, passwd:string){
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwd).then( 
      () => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((token:string) => {
          this.token = token;
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        });
        this.router.navigateByUrl('');
        return true;
      }).catch(
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          return false;
        }

      );
  }

  getToken(){
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
      (token:string) => this.token = token
    );
    return this.token;
  }

  logout(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    this.token = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the request you're making? why not read the error message from the response to display the error message

Comment: If you try to register and the email already exists, Firebase will automatically give an error message saying "Email address already exists". However this happens when you actually call the function of firebase for registering. I want to check if the user exists in the database, WHILE I'm entering an email.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely create a service with call to FireBase. In your code snippet you are not sending any requests. 
After you make a service, you should subscribe to you input field with `.valueChanges` and in `.subscribe` method check it's validity via service.

Comment: I do have a service. I'll edit my question with the service code...

Comment: You should add method with fetching results of search in your table of emails. And in subscription to valueChanges of your email control you probably want to use throttle operator unless you want to fetch all the data and check for duplicates on every keypress. Also it will be a good idea to prefetch some emails based on search with username or something like that

Comment: You'll need docs on reactive forms - https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and on throttle - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttle.html.If you have trouble using observables instead of promises - better read https://www.learnrxjs.io. I believe you can't cache emails from firebase, so use auth/email-already-in-use from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetch-sign-inmethods-for-email. Also check out docs on validator on Forms https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user already is registered with a given email address, call the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetch-sign-inmethods-for-email). For an example of how to call this method, see the Firebase documentation on [differentiating accounts from various providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#differentiating_emailpassword_from_email_link).

Comment: Something like: **if(firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(control.value)){ ... }**?

Comment: If `control.value` contains the email address, then that's indeed how you'd call it.

Comment: So now when I entered an email that is not in the database I still get error messages, even the first error message "Email Required". How is this possible?

Comment: You keep referring to "the database", which I'm not sure I understand correctly. If the email address is used for a Firebase Authentication account, calling the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method will return the provider(s) that the email is used for. If you're having problems making that work, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).